# JSP: Request to initiate Servlet instance and return without waiting for servlet to complete

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP programming and need help for one of my requirement.

My jsp page to call servlet instance and return to same page without waiting for servlet to complete. The servlet to receive parameters from web user and peform some long running backend data process.it will update databases & logs once the process completes.

Can anyone please share sample code to return without waiting for servlet to complete?

Answer (score 0):

Call servlet using Ajax and then send back part of result when you need it. After you receive this result, display it on the page with Javascript/JQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/